# How to find the smallest N dimensional simplex from a set of points that contains a given point?

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, bounding-box, simplex, analytical

I've looked all over google and stack but haven't found an answer to this problem yet. I keep finding results relating to the simplex method or results for finding the smallest arbitrary simplex (i.e. the vertices are not constrained). Neither can I think of an analytical solution.

Given a set of N-dimensional points, **M**, and an arbitrary N-dimensional point, *q*, how do I find the smallest N-dimensional simplex, ***S***, that contains *q* as an interior point if the vertices of ***S*** must be in **M**? I'm sure I could solve it with an optimization, but I'd like an analytical solution if possible. A deterministic algorithm would be ok, as well.

I was originally using a K nearest neighbors approach, but then I realized it's possible that the N+1 nearest neighbors to *q* won't necessarily create a simplex that contains *q*.

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited it.

Comment: By "smallest simplex", do you mean by volume, or something else? BTW, this seems like a hard problem; do you have in mind specific values or value ranges of N and M?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this is O(N^2) using an iterative process very similar to K-NN, but perhaps there is a more efficient way. This should return the minimum simplex in terms of the number of vertices.

For each coordinate *i* in *q*, we can iterate through all elements of **M**, comparing the  *q_i* and *m_i*. We will select the two points in **M** which give us the min positive difference and min negative difference. If we repeat this process for every coordinate, then we should have our min set **S**.

Am I understanding the problem correctly?